# Where is "Major Kyle"?

Tags: mass-effect

On the "Major Kyle" assignment, I successfully landed on Presrop and found a building in which I had a conversation with a guard over intercom. After using my "Charm" skill, I was able to enter the building and nobody attacked me.

When I look at the map, I see an orange symbol in the upper left room,I checked both rooms (on each level) and Major Kyle is not there nor anything that may help me to finish this assignment.

Is that a Bug or the Major is hiding elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Major is hiding elsewhere. There is actually a second building nearby where you find Major Kyle and end the mission.

This video walkthrough will help you find where he's hiding. (The relevant portion is around 5:20 in)

Answer (score 2):

Outside should be another building,the tan one that isn't very tall. look for the green light on it.

Check here if you did everything ok (around 2 min).

Answer (score 2):

If you use "Charm" you are allowed to enter in that building. But Father Kyle is not there, is the other one. I had the same problem a couple of years ago when I played Mass Effect.